# Calling request from Streamlit and getting ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Tags: python, post, request, streamlit

I have a Streamlit App that can start docker containers and send a request to them. The container part runs fine, but when I send my request with files uploaded by the user, it returns the error `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`. The relevant (shortened) code snippet would be:

```py
    def send_request_to_retrain(self, port, upload_files):

        url = f"{self.URL}:{port}/retrain"

        headers = {}
        files = get_request_files(upload_files)
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

and the file-preparation is:

```py
def get_request_files(upload_files):
    files = []

    for file in upload_files:
        name = file.name
        content = file.read()
        mime_type = file.type
        if 'train' in name:
            files.append(('trainingdata',(name,content,mime_type)))
        elif 'test' in name:
            files.append(('testingdata',(name,content,mime_type)))
        elif 'options' in name:
            files.append(('options',(name,content,mime_type)))

    # no validation needed as done already previously
    return files
```

so a step by step of the process:

1. A user enters all needed info to start a container and uploads the three files (for this example case, it could be a different amount but this is the classic case)
2. The container is started (can confirm this works fine)
3. The request to the below url is sent
4. The error occurs

If I run the request code separately without streamlit to one of the generated containers like the following, it works as expected and intended.

```py
import requests

url = "exampleurl"

payload = {}
files=[
  ('trainingdata',('train.json',open('filepath/train.json','rb'),'application/json')),
  ('testingdata',('test.json',open('filepath/test.json','rb'),'application/json')),
  ('options',('options.json',open('filepath/options.json','rb'),'application/json'))
]
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

I tried to add a time.sleep(3) before the request in my app as it was recommended in another thread but that did not help.